# Why does my component unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the below warning in the console.

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>
> Please check the code for the ProgressBar component.

It seems to me this is because of the `componentWillUnmount` that happens after the first `componentDidMount` (see console output at the bottom). The `componentWillUnmount` happens before data has arrived from the server. When the data finally arrives, `setState` is trying to work with something unmounted.

But why is there an `componentWillUnmount` there? I would expect the unmount to happen only after `setState` is called (and data has arrived from the server). So the component would still be there for `setState` to work with.

```
class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { progress: 0 };
    }

    loadProgressFromServer() {
        let url = '/progress/' + this.props.topic_name;
        console.log("LOADING progress FROM SERVER");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("finished loading from server");
                this.setState({ progress: data['progress'] });
            }.bind(this)           
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("didmount");
        this.loadProgressFromServer();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("willunmount");
    }

    render() {
        let progress = (this.state.progress * 100).toFixed(0);
        return (
            <div className="progress" ref="pb">
                <div className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={ progress } aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={{ width: progress +"%" }}>
                    { progress + "%" }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The console output:

```
didmount
LOADING progress FROM SERVER
willunmount
didmount
LOADING progress FROM SERVER
finished loading from server
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the ProgressBar component.
finished loading from server
```

EDIT:
There is no higher order component.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ProgressBar topic_name='name of topic' />,
    document.getElementById('progressbar')
);
```

Comment: _"But why is there an "willunmount" there?"_ Didn't you put it there?

Comment: My question is, why is it triggered. Why is the component being unmounted before the AJAX request completes.

Comment: What does the higher component do? To me it seems that a process different from your ProgressBar unmounts the ProgressBar component. Maybe it's better to make your container handle the ajax call and update your ProgressBar without the progressbar actually knowing what's happening

Comment: It would seem the data you are pulling isn't meant to be consumed by the progress bar. Therefore, the ajax call should be made by the parent component and passed as a prop to the ProgressBar so it knows when to close. That would also make the ProgressBar a reusable component.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps (note the `async: false`) - the default value for async is true, which returns data from the server after the component is rendered - setting  `this.setState({ progress: data['progress'] });` causes the warning messages you're getting

```
loadProgressFromServer() {
        let url = '/progress/' + this.props.topic_name;
        console.log("LOADING progress FROM SERVER");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: false
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("finished loading from server");
                this.setState({ progress: data['progress'] });
            }.bind(this)           
        })
    }
```

Comment: This does solve the problem. Warning is gone and unmount happens only after "finished loading from server". It's being depreciated, but still helps a lot to understand what's going on. It's not very intuitive to me how `setState` is triggered before data has arrived, because `success` would only be triggered after data has arrived I'd have thought.

Comment: Synchronous XHRs on the main thread have been deprecated for a very long time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests